# How to use pandas to pivot a table while changing values to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm working with a pandas dataframe where my df looks like the image below (I've simplified for the sake of the questions)...

```
df = pd.read_csv("./filepath/filename.csv")
print(df)
```

`Output:`

[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j3zK.png)

I'm wanting to pivot the `type` column while setting the values within to true or false so that the end result looks like so:

[Desired outcome dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxUm5.png)

I'm thinking that I need to somehow use `pd.pivot_table` to accomplish this but I can't seem to figure it out exactly. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please post dataframe as text and not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'index_id':[1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6], 
   'type': ['h','g','h','g','h','g','h','g',]
})

df

   index_id type
0         1    h
1         1    g
2         2    h
3         3    g
4         4    h
5         5    g
6         5    h
7         6    g
```

There could be a nicer sentence, but this one does the job:

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df,columns='type', index='index_id', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero).fillna(0).astype(bool)

type          g      h
index_id              
1          True   True
2         False   True
3          True  False
4         False   True
5          True   True
6          True  False
```

Ok, here is another, possibly more laconic solution:

```
pd.crosstab(df['index_id'],columns=df['type']).astype(bool)                                                  

type          g      h
index_id              
1          True   True
2         False   True
3          True  False
4         False   True
5          True   True
6          True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Comment: This doesn't group the index_id column together though